# having an issue when installing pygraphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm having an issue when trying to install `pygraphviz` via `pip`. It took a long time, but I managed to install `graphviz`.

```
(base) C:\Users\>pip install graphviz --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.19.2)
```

I am using `Python 3.9.7` and the OS is Windows 10. When I use Anaconda Prompt and type `pip install pygraphviz`, I receive the following error.

```
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
    Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-krs5aqg9\\pygraphviz_28eebe5841e1478493b04aa9e79a4fcb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-krs5aqg9\\pygraphviz_28eebe5841e1478493b04aa9e79a4fcb\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users \AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qvuual1u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include\pygraphviz'
         cwd: C:\Users \AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-krs5aqg9\pygraphviz_28eebe5841e1478493b04aa9e79a4fcb\
    writing pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
    adding license file 'LICENSE'
    writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pygraphviz
    copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pygraphviz
    running build_ext
    building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\ \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-krs5aqg9\\pygraphviz_28eebe5841e1478493b04aa9e79a4fcb\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users \\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-krs5aqg9\\pygraphviz_28eebe5841e1478493b04aa9e79a4fcb\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users \AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qvuual1u\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Include\pygraphviz' Check the logs for full command output.
```

The only error that makes sense is  `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.`, but I already installed the latest version.

[image]

Comment: You have `C++ Redistributable`, but need `Microsoft C++ Build Tools`

Comment: Since you have `conda`, you could also give `conda install -c conda-forge pygraphviz` a try

Comment: Or try installing it (download and pass the file to *PIP*) from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygraphviz.

Comment: @FlyingTeller When installing VS 2022, the installer included all the SDKs. Also, I gave a ````conda```` try, but it did not work. ````Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.````

Answer (score 0):

Try to install from your Anaconda environment:

`conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz`